# How to update time with sntp using ntp.conf file

Tags: macos, time, sonoma, ntp

After the recent daylight saving time change, my macOS (Sonoma v14.1.1) clock no longer shows correct date and time. When I enable "Set date and time automatically" it reverts to January 22, 2023 and a wrong time.

Therefore, I would like to manually synchronise my computer's clock with a time server. I would like to use Oxford's University time servers. I use `sntp` command.

```
sudo sntp -sS ntp1.ox.ac.uk
```

The command produces five sets of the following output:

```
sntp: Exchange failed: Timeout
sntp_exchange {
        result: 6 (Timeout)
        header: 00 (li:0 vn:0 mode:0)
       stratum: 00 (0)
          poll: 00 (1)
     precision: 00 (1.000000e+00)
         delay: 0000.0000 (0.000000000)
    dispersion: 0000.0000 (0.000000000)
           ref: 00000000 ("    ")
         t_ref: 00000000.00000000 (0.000000000)
            t1: E8F7357E.A265F0F5 (3908515198.634367999)
            t2: 00000000.00000000 (0.000000000)
            t3: 00000000.00000000 (0.000000000)
            t4: 00000000.00000000 (0.000000000)
        offset: FFFFFFFF8B846540.AECD078580000000 (-1954257599.317183971)
         delay: FFFFFFFF1708CA81.5D9A0F0B00000000 (-3908515198.634367943)
          mean: 0000000000000000.0000000000000000 (0.000000000)
         error: 0000000000000000.0000000000000000 (0.000000000)
          addr: 129.67.1.164
}
```

and exits with the following error message:

```
sntp: Clock select failed
```

My NTP server configuration is located in `/private/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
server  ntp0.ox.ac.uk
server  ntp1.ox.ac.uk
server  ntp2.ox.ac.uk
server  ntp3.ox.ac.uk
```

My questions are:

1. How do I make sure that the `sntp` command uses the nth.conf file above? At the moment I have to supply the NTP server address manually to the `sntp` command.
2. What do I need to change for the `sntp` command to succeed and set the time?

Comment: That setting uses NTP to set the date. I think the problem is with your Mac's clock, not the mechanism used to set it.

Comment: As @Barmar says.  But also I can't access any of your ntp servers (are they behind firewall?). Does `sntp pool.ntp.org` work?  And, on macOS the `timed` daemon will continue to set your clock unless you take steps to disable it.

Comment: @Gilby Doesn't unchecking that checkbox disable it?

Comment: I hadn't realised how those settings have changed with 14.0 and do now give you control of `timed`.  I use ChronyControl to set my clock which does disable `timed`.  But I think you have a different problem with time reverting to last January. What happens if you use `Set...` of Date and Time in System Settings?

Comment: Yes, `sntp pool.ntp.org` does work. It produces the following output:
`+0.102662 +/- 0.100008 pool.ntp.org 129.250.35.250`. I think you are right, Oxford University time servers are only reachable within a University network.

Comment: If I set the Date/Time manually via GUI in macOS, it works. As soon as I set it to automatic setting via GUI it reverts to January 2023. My second question remains, how do I ensure `sntp` uses my `ntp.conf` file?